# Remove padding from fxLayoutGap last element of row

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I have a problem using fxLayoutGap. The last column of my list has a padding and I don't want it.

How to keep fxLayoutGap (space between cards) and remove the padding from the last column ? Thank !

```html
<div fxFlexFill fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayoutGap="20px grid" style="margin-right:-20px;">
  <div fxHide.lt-sm="true" fxFlex="calc(25%-20px)" fxFlex.md="33">
    <div fxFlexFill fxLayoutAlign="center center">
      <mat-card (click)="addAdvert()" class="mat-card-add-button">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxFlex="100%">
          <span style="font-size:32px;text-align:center">+<br />test</span>
        </div>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="calc(25%-20px)" fxFlex.md="33" *ngFor="let product of products | slice:0:3">
    <div style="border:1px solid #ccc" fxFlexFill fxLayoutAlign="center stretch">
      <mat-card class="ad">
        <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
        <mat-card-title>test</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>test</p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-divider [inset]="true"></mat-divider>
        <mat-card-actions align="end">
          <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="edit" matTooltipShowDelay="800">
            <mat-icon>mode_edit</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="delete" matTooltipShowDelay="800">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem (in red):

[image]

**Update**

I used **Abdul Rafay's** solution but here a new problem:

[image]

Comment: fxLayoutAlign="center center" is the best solution on parent element of ngFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** try assigning classes to your elements through `ngFor` here:

```
<div fxFlexFill fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayoutGap="20px grid" style="margin-right:-20px;">
  <div fxFlex="calc(25%-20px)" fxFlex.md="33"
    *ngFor="let product of products;let i = index"
    [ngClass]="'product-'+getClassName(i)">
    ...
```

**.ts**:

```
  counter: number = 0;

  getClassName(index) {
    if(index%4 === 0)
      this.counter = 0;
    this.counter++;
    switch(this.counter) {
      case 1:
        return "first"
      case 2:
        return "second"
      case 3:
        return "third"
      default:
        return "fourth"
    }
  }
```

then add these `css` styles:

```
.product-first[fxFlex] {
  padding-right: 20px !important;
}
.product-second[fxFlex] {
  padding-left: 6.66px !important;
  padding-right: 13.34px !important; 
}
.product-third[fxFlex] {
  padding-left: 13.34px !important;
  padding-right: 6.66px !important;
}
.product-fourth[fxFlex] {
  padding-left: 20px !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

I'm not sure if it's the best way but it works.

**Old ans:** Simply add a `css` styles:

```
[fxFlex]:last-of-type { padding-right:0px !important; }
```

If there's more than one row:

```
[fxFlex]:nth-child(4n) { padding-right:0px !important; }
```

If there's more fxFlex elements, you can assign a class:

```
<div fxFlexFill fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayoutGap="20px grid" style="margin-right:-20px;">
    <div class="padding-fix" fxHide.lt-sm="true" fxFlex="calc(25%-20px)" fxFlex.md="33">
    ...

.padding-fix[fxFlex]:nth-child(4n) { padding-right:0px !important; }
```

Comment: It seems to be good but this style takes all fxFlex of my page. How can I specifiy just one of them ? Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: I was little bit excited to find a solution but I didn't see something wrong in your answer. The last item is is slightly larger than others. I gonna update my first post with in a screenshot.

Comment: you can try this:

`.padding-fix[fxFlex] { padding-right:23.33px !important; }`
 
`.padding-fix[fxFlex]:nth-child(4n) { padding-right:0px !important; }`

Comment: Unfortunately, same problem. The picture of the last item is bigger than others.

Comment: It would be easier if you could please replicate your problem in a stackblitz

Comment: Your last solution works but I think there is problem with material design (fxLayoutGap and grid option). Thank you very much for your help ! :)

Comment: @JoeAllen Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Just do this small trick.

Remove fxLayoutGap and add a margin to the child element and add the minus value of that same margin to the parent element.

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" style="margin-right: -16px;">
    <div fxFlex="calc(50% - 16px)" style="margin-right: 16px;">

    </div>
    <div fxFlex="calc(50% - 16px)" style="margin-right: 16px;">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

found on stackoverflow: you have to add grid to the gap.

```
fxLayoutGap="5rem grid"
```

See documentation:
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayoutGap-API

Answer (score 0):

you can specifiy the last item in row with index in ngFor, lets say 4 columns:

```
[class.flexLastItem]="((i-3) % 4 === 0)"
```

finally just css

```
.flexLastItem{ margin-right: 0 !important; }
```