# How to handle the last element of each row in angular flex layout when using 'row wrap' with 'gap'

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

The last element of each row has the gap defined by the fxLayoutGap, which results in a bad layout with the container bigger than it should be.

[image: example image]
As you can see the modal has a wider white-border on the right side because there is also the margin of the last element of the row.
I've also asked directly to the angular-flex-layout team but maybe i can find a workaround: [github quesiton](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/753)

In the project i'm working on there are lots of scenario where i have a list of components displayed like

```
<div fxFlex="500px" 
    fxLayout="row wrap"
    fxLayoutGap="10px">
    <my-component *ngFor="let x of myList" [someInput]="x" ></my-component>
</div>
```

I have a container of fixed width and some components that also have fixed width. Sometimes i know how many components i'm going to display in each row, but most of the time I don't.
Usually when I know how many element i have to display for each row (eg, in a calendar) i calculate the required width of the container by doing `(child_width + gap) * desired_children_per_row)` i should subtract the `gap` once because the last element of each row should not have the gap, but doing that way there will be not enough space and the result will be like`desired_children_per_row - 1`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/lacolaco-angular-flex-layout-example-t7raqx
in the example toggle `threePerRow` to see that the last element has the margin.

Comment: check this url. There is a solution. See if this can help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168018/remove-padding-from-fxlayoutgap-last-element-of-row/52169395