# Padding problem at last element in every row when using fxLayoutGap in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm currently facing a big issue in the https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout library. The problem is the `fxLayoutGap` setting for grid likely designs but just as a flexbox.

The actual problem is that when I use this settings `fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="25px grid" fxFlexFill` on each box/grid element to add a gap between each boxes, I'm also getting a gap at the last element of each row. In my eyes there should be no gap to prevent a useless padding there:

[image]

I did a lot of research. The most nearest answer on SO is this one:

[Remove padding from fxLayoutGap last element of row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168018/remove-padding-from-fxlayoutgap-last-element-of-row)

But this answer is just about the las element in a single row so the answer don't helps. So I've continued searching and found this:

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/363

This is an issue in the actual library. But sadly the developer says that this is not a `bug` and should be fixed by the developer. But I think this is not true...

He provided this answer here...

```
Simply add a CSS style [fxFlex]:last-of-type { margin-right:15px; }
```

... and closed the ticket: `Closing as a will-not-fix issue`. So not very helpful. After trying the answer this way `[fxFlex]::nth-child(4n) { padding-right:0px !important; }` I've found out the the last element get's bigger which looks bad:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<div id="list" class="shadow-box-list" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="25px grid" fxFlexFill>
  <div class="widget" *ngFor="let element of elements" [fxFlex]="fxFlex">
    <div class="shadow-box-list-widget-content mat-elevation-z3" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
      <div class="name">{{element.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So does anyone had the same issue/problem before and can share the answer with me? I really don't know how to solve this.

Comment: So initially i would say there should be a padding left and right on start and end items, which will look nice with some breathing space. But If you don't want that so kindly tell if I am not wrong every 4th item will be the last item in a row, right or not? 
Do you have 4 items in each row or just items wrap around in single container?

Comment: @WahabShah yes thats true.

Comment: If that is the case each row has only 4 items in it why don't you target it with css 
nth-child(4). It will target the 4th child of container

Comment: @WahabShah My mistake. I've updated the answer. Forgot to replace it with my current try using `:nth-child`

Comment: the width issue you mean with nth-child(4) for last element?

Comment: @WahabShah Yes. When I set the padding to 0, the element itself get's bigger which looks bad compared to the other ones.

Comment: Have you tried setting width to flex-item? I guess that will do the trick.

Comment: @WahabShah This width is 25% each item. It should be responsive so setting hard px width is not working

Comment: @WahabShah Whats now? Do you had an idea the last days?

Comment: Sorry got a bit busy. Can you set up a stackblitz link so I can see that?