# Not receiving variable value from service in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've developed a cookie checker service in my application which should check the status of my cookie consent popup:

```
@Injectable()
export class CookieCheckService implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public hasConsented = false;
  private cookieStatusChangeSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private ccService: NgcCookieConsentService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.ccService.hasConsented()) {
      this.hasConsented = true;
    }

    console.log(this.hasConsented);

    this.cookieStatusChangeSubscription = this.ccService.statusChange$.subscribe(
      (event: NgcStatusChangeEvent) => {
        this.hasConsented = event.status === this.ccService.getStatus().allow;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.cookieStatusChangeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

My idea was it to call this now from any component where I need to check the status so for example in my footer where I display Google Maps:

```
@Component({
  selector   : 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls  : ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent {
  hasConsented = false;

  constructor(
    private cookieCheckService: CookieCheckService
  ) {
    this.hasConsented = cookieCheckService.hasConsented;
  }
}
```

Normally when I press allow now I want to make my Google Maps widget visible via `ngIf` but somehow I'm not getting any value from my service - also initially. What I'm doing wrong here?

**Update**

Because someone asked: `this.ccService.getStatus()` is an interface that returns:

```
export interface NgcCookieConsentStatus {
    allow?: 'allow';
    deny?: 'deny';
    dismiss?: 'dismiss';
}
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan added an update which explains your comment.

Comment: What do you do with `hasConsented` in the component?

Comment: @ConnorsFan As described in my question I'm using it in a ngIf to show/hide content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues

1. Lifecycle hooks like `OnInit()`, `OnDestroy()` are meant for components and directives. They do not work with services.
2. `this.hasConsented` in the service is assigned asynchronously. You might have to change the behavior. But for a quick workaround, you could move everything to the constructor.

Try the following

Service

```js
@Injectable()
export class CookieCheckService {
  public hasConsented = false;
  private cookieStatusChangeSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private ccService: NgcCookieConsentService) {
    if (this.ccService.hasConsented()) {
      this.hasConsented = true;
    }

    console.log(this.hasConsented);

    this.cookieStatusChangeSubscription = this.ccService.statusChange$.subscribe(
      (event: NgcStatusChangeEvent) => { this.hasConsented = event.status === this.ccService.getStatus().allow; }
    );
  }
}
```

**Update**

To reflect the changes to `hasConsented` (service) in the component you could make it an RxJS [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject). Also you could supply `{ providedIn: 'root' }` to the `@Injectable` decorator of the service to make sure it's a [singleton](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) (one single instance of the service throughout the app).

Service

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CookieCheckService {
  private hasConsentedSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  public get hasConsented() {
    return this.hasConsentedSource.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(private ccService: NgcCookieConsentService) {
    if (this.ccService.hasConsented()) {
      this.hasConsentedSource.next(true);
    }

    console.log(this.hasConsented);

    this.ccService.statusChange$.subscribe(
      (event: NgcStatusChangeEvent) => { 
        this.hasConsentedSource.next(event.status === this.ccService.getStatus().allow); 
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can subscribe to it in the component.

Component

```
@Component({
  selector   : 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls  : ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent {
  hasConsented = false;

  constructor(private cookieCheckService: CookieCheckService) {
    this.cookieCheckService.hasConsented.subscribe(
      status => { this.hasConsented = status }
    );
  }
}
```

Now the `hasConsented` value in the component will be updated each time a new value is pushed to the `hasConsented` value in the service.

Comment: Does it also register a change and returns it to the component? And do I need to destroy the subscription on the ccService somehow?

Comment: Do you want the `hasConsented` value to be pushed to the components everytime it's value is changed in the service?

Comment: Yes, thats the idea. I'm new to Angular and TS for your understanding. So if I press Decline again or Accept it want to show/hide everything checked via ngIf.

Comment: I LOVE IT! Thanks a lot for your help. It's working awesome!

Comment: Maybe you also have an idea about this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870038/padding-problem-at-last-element-in-every-row-when-using-fxlayoutgap-in-angular That would be awesome!!!

Comment: I don't think I understand that problem. But will post if I find a way.